# SELECT sql_function(...) vs SELECT * FROM sql_function(...)

Tags: postgresql, functions

I'm reading the PostgreSQL documentation for the first time and when facing SQL functions I think I have understood all the basics, but still can't see the difference between `SELECT sql_function(...)` and `SELECT * FROM sql_function(...)` and when to use one or the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typically use a function in `FROM` if it is a *set-returning function* (SRF). Such functions return a result set rather than a single value or tuple.

But, confusingly, this is not written in stone in PostgreSQL:

- You can also call a SRF in the `SELECT` list, as in `SELECT f()`.

  As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) says:

  > Functions returning sets can also be called in the select list of a query. For each row that the query generates by itself, the set-returning function is invoked, and an output row is generated for each element of the function's result set.
- You can use any function in the `FROM` clause. It is then treated as a SRF that returns only a single row.

Comment: Any known drawback with calling a SFR with SELECT or an escalar function with SELECT * FROM?

Comment: The first can lead to unexpected behavior if you have more than one table function in the select list, but other than that, no.

Answer (score 0):

The former is used on a scalar function (i.e. it returns a scalar result / single value), the latter is used on a [table function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/xfunc-tablefunctions.html) (a function that returns a result set of values as opposed to a single value), which is why the syntax is to select from it as opposed to the former.

Solomon Rutzky does a beautiful job describing the differences between a Scalar and Table function in his answer to this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754663/difference-between-scalar-table-valued-and-aggregate-functions-in-sql-server). (It's Microsoft SQL Server specific but the concepts are the same, especially for your high level question in this context.)

Comment: note the question is in regards to postgresql which has different implementations than sql server in this area. [Some examples (link)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=552e9efdfb68565890cfbb5a3e2ae2f7)